# power rule not working with $\sqrt{-1}$

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation

I was recently looking at why one of my answers turned out incorrectly using this [Power Rule](http://www.rapidtables.com/math/number/exponent.htm#power) $(a^n)^m = a^{n\times m}$
.

Trying to solve $(-1)^{3/2} = ?$

I found that

- $(-1)^{1/2\cdot 3}$ would become $((-1)^{1/2})^3$. This becomes $-i$.

and

- $(-1)^{3*1/2}$ would become $((-1)^3)^{1/2}$. This becomes $i$.

I know how to solve both, and understand the answer should be $-i$.

---

Why can I multiply as $1/2 \cdot 3$ and not $3\cdot 1/2$ ? Are there additional conditions in the Power Rule that I have missed?

Comment: the power rule doesn't work in $$\mathbb{C}$$

Comment: $((-1)^{1/2})^3=(\{-i,i\})^3=\{-i,i\}$ and $((-1)^3)^{1/2}=(\{-1\})^{1/2}=\{-i,i\}$. It works! :p

Comment: @Arjang Someone needs to review their complex numbers basic arithmetic.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexExponentiation.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more reliable rule is
$$a^b=e^{b\ln(a)}.$$
Now the answer you get depends on how you interpret $\ln(a).$

If you consider the complex logarithm to be a multivalued function, you may get multiple answers. In the case $a=-1,$ $\ln(-1)=i\pi(1+2k)$ where $k$ is an integer,
$\frac32\ln(-1)=i\pi\left(\frac32+3k\right)$ where $k$ is an integer,
and $e^{i\pi((3/2)+3k)}$
is $i$ when $k$ is odd and $-i$ when $k$ is even. 
So $i$ and $-i$ both are values of $(-1)^{3/2}.$

On the other hand, if you take a branch of the logarithm in which $\ln(-1)=i\pi,$
then $(-1)^{3/2}=e^{i3\pi/2}=-i.$